# Regex for escaped characters highlighting

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building an autocomplete in JavaScript that needs to highlight words when doing a search:

[image: highlighting example]

That works fine, but there's an issue with escaped characters.
When trying to highlight a text with escaped characters (for example `regex &>< example`), the following is happening:

[image: regex highlighting]

That's happening because I am doing the following:

```
element.innerHTML.replace(/a/g, highlight)

function highlight(str) {
  return '<span class="foo"' + '>' + str + '</span>';
}
```

and `innerHTML` includes the word `&amp;`, so it makes sense.

In conclusion, I need a way to solve that so I would like a function that:

- receives `a` and `regex <br> example` and returns `regex &lt;br&gt; ex<span class="foo">a</span>mple`
- receives `r` and `regex <br> example` and returns `<span class="foo">r</span>egex &lt;b<span class="foo">r</span>&gt; example`
- receives `<` and `regex <br> example` and returns `regex <span class="foo">&lt;</span>br&gt; example`

The entries may or may not contain html blocks, see the issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8rd8mbm9/2/) (search for `<br>` or `&`)

Comment: If you don't want the entities returned, use `textContent` to get the content, and `innerHTML` to set it with the span included ?

Comment: `textContent` has characters escaped (i.e.: `&amp;`), its just excluding html like `span`s for example, so that won't work

Comment: This looks like another example of those `You can't parse html with regular expressions` scenarios: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/25216

Comment: @AndrewShepherd There is no parsing nor regular expressions involved here... (unless you count the single char `/a/` as a whole regex)

Comment: Is the `itemElem` populated with the escaped (non-highlighted) text and then the highlighter will attempt to include the `span` to highlight the text? Or will a function be given the raw unescaped string and then set the highlighted escaped text to the `itemElem`?

Comment: @JasonCust, the element is populated once, so the function should receive the unscaped string and then generate a escaped string with the html modified to highlight the given word

Comment: @lante - [Did you try it?](https://jsfiddle.net/czdrg2j3/1/)

Comment: I updated my answer to cover both scenarios. I hope it helps! :)

Comment: @adeneo sorry for the misunderstood, at that moment `innerHTML` is already escaped: https://jsfiddle.net/8rd8mbm9/

Comment: What are you using on the server side?

Comment: @RobertRocha nothing, just plain javascript on the client

Comment: What you are trying to do is autocomplete. And if you do have spmething on the server side this can be so much simpler than using regex's.

Comment: What are you comparing the input to?

Comment: And I still don't get it, if you want to get rid of the entities you'd still use `textContent` -> **https://jsfiddle.net/8rd8mbm9/1/**

Comment: @adeneo I updated the question with a working example with the issue, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8rd8mbm9/2/) and try to look for `&` for example

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use e.g. [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).

Comment: Btw: What's the point for not using e.g. typeahead.js?

Comment: Using innerHTML is evil as it destroys events and regenerates the DOM

Comment: @dude thanks for the suggestions, but what I need is much more simpler. Also, typeahead doesn't cover a use case that I need and that's why I am building another autocomplete, but thats not part of the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only returns a new string with the intended replacements. The original string is unchanged.

```js
var str = 'replace me';
var str2 = str.replace(/e/g, 'E');

// For display only
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
  str: str,
  str2: str2
}, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Therefore the code needs to set the returned value from the replace back to the desired element.

Also, `innerHTML` will return the escaped text rather than the unescaped text. This could be unescaped itself within the function but why bother if you can use `textContent`. However by using `innerHTML` when it's time to set the highlighted text to the element it will auto-escape the text for us. :)

**UPDATE**: the values are passed to the function and then set to the element:

*NOTES:*

- *The regexp could probably be made a bit more robust to avoid having to handle the special case using `lastIndex`*
- *There needs to be some protection on the input as someone could provide a nasty regexp pattern. There is a minimal protection check in this example.*

```js
higlightElemById('a', 'regex &>< example', 'a');
higlightElemById('b', 'regex &>< example', '&');
higlightElemById('c', 'regex <br> example', '<');
higlightElemById('d', 'regex <br> example', 'e');
higlightElemById('e', 'regex <br> example', '[aex]');

function higlightElemById(id, str, match) {
  var itemElem = document.getElementById(id);
  // minimal regexp escape to prevent shenanigans
  var safeMatch = match.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
  // construct regexp to match highlight text
  var regexp = new RegExp('(.*?)(' + safeMatch + ')', 'g');
  var text = '';
  var lastIndex;
  var matches;
  
  while (matches = regexp.exec(str)) {
    // Escape the non-matching prefix
    text += escapeHTML(matches[1]);
    // Highlight the match
    text += highlight(matches[2]);
    // Cache the lastIndex in case no regexp at end
    lastIndex = regexp.lastIndex;
  }

  if (text) {
    text += escapeHTML(str.substr(lastIndex));
  } else {
    text += escapeHTML(str);
  }

  itemElem.innerHTML = text;
}

function highlight(str) {
  return '<span class="myHighlightClass">' + str + '</span>';
}

function escapeHTML(html) {
  this.el = this.el || document.createElement('textarea');

  this.el.textContent = html;
  return this.el.innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.myHighlightClass {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am seeing an extra case which is not covered:
https://jsfiddle.net/gemxuc3e/
I updated the question to clarify

Comment: @lante What is your desired output in that case? Would "<br>" be escaped or not in the input and would it need to be in the escaped in the output element?

Comment: See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8rd8mbm9/2/) an example, the entries may or may not contain html blocks (I can't forbid the user to put html blocks as entries) search for `br` or `&`

Comment: @lante Does it need to be a global match or would highlighting only the first match work?

Comment: global match since its an autocomplete

Comment: @lante I made some edits but in all honesty if you keep changing the original question it makes it very hard to answer. It's already at a point of possibly needing a bounty.